# add.pie() not rendering pie chart on plotted map

Tags: r, plot, maps, pie-chart

I plotted a map using the following code.

```
#plot map
map("worldHires", "Canada", col="grey80", fill=TRUE, projection="gilbert", orientation= c(90,0,225))
lon <- c(-72, -66, -107, -154)  #fake longitude vector
lat <- c(81.7, 64.6, 68.3, 60)  #fake latitude vector
coord <- mapproject(lon, lat, projection="gilbert", orientation=c(90, 0, 225))  
points(coord, pch=20, cex=2, col="red")
```

Then tried plotting a pie using the following codes

```
#plot pie
add.pie(z=c(10,60), x=83, y=-72, radius=1, col=c("orange", "red"),    labels="l")
xyz <- make.xyz(lon[1],lat[1],100,200)
add.pie(z=xyz$z, x=xyz$x, y=xyz$y, radius=0.3, col=c("orange", "blue"), labels="", edges=200)
add.pie(z=rpois(4,10), x=lon[1]+5, y=lat[1]+5, radius=0.3, col=c("orange", "blue"), labels="", edges=200)
```

All these codes execute fine, but none renders a pie chart on my plotted map.

Does anyone know what I could be missing here. I know I can plot on my map, because if I run more `points()` commands, I am able to see those points overlaid.

Answer (score 0):

To get it to plot in a place where you can see the pie chart, you can try the following code below.  This gives you a place to start but not an explanation of what is going on.

```
library(maps)
library(mapproj)
library(mapdata)
library(mapplots)

map("worldHires", "Canada", col="grey80", fill=TRUE, projection="gilbert", orientation= c(90,0,225))
lon <- c(-72, -66, -107, -154)  #fake longitude vector
lat <- c(81.7, 64.6, 68.3, 60)  #fake latitude vector
coord <- mapproject(lon, lat, projection="gilbert", orientation=c(90, 0, 225))  
points(coord, pch=20, cex=2, col="red")
```

Adding the pie chart based on how you used `coord` above and using the documentation example to set z.

```
coord2 <- mapproject(-72, 83, projection = "gilbert", orientation=c(90, 0, 225))
add.pie(z=rpois(6,10), x=coord2$x, y=coord2$y, radius = 0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that you had problems with the coordinates being outside the plot and also the size of the pie chart.  Initially it was very large.

Comment: I dont think so. Because I tried various sizes and also the coordinates were the same that finally showed me the plot. The issue was the way the ad.pie() function was reading my coordinates, it didnt seem to understand them.

When I changed x=-72 to x=coord2$x, the function rendered the graphic. So I'm not sure the reason behind it, but converting the coordinates to the right bject form seemed to do the trick.